# jquery select tag change enevt no use

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, select

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="${request.getContextPath()}/web/easyui/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#course").change(function(){
                alert(1);

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="course">
        <option value="1">option a</option>
        <option value="2">option b</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

I select "option a",then select "option b",but the code "alert(1)" does not run.why?
why the change event is no use?

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser console?

Comment: Please make sure that path to jQuery is correct.?

Comment: your code is work like charm just check jqury path

Comment: Check if you have **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined** printed on the browser console. If so, then the path to jquery is wrong.

Comment: sorry , i check again ,it works.but i cut some code from a  complicated page ,that page do not work.

Comment: i know ,i use easyui,so the DOM changed,so it no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```js
$('#course').on('change', function() {
  alert(1); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="course">
  <option value="1">option a</option>
  <option value="2">option b</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is work like charm just check jQuery path

Try adding..

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#course").change(function(){
                alert(1);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="course">
        <option value="1">option a</option>
        <option value="2">option b</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```